# Excel add-in development by using COM library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I want to create an Excel add-in by using Visual Studio 2015, there is an option for this, that is VSTO. While, because of some reasons, I need to create it by using COM library rather than VSTO.

I find there was a project template named Shared Add-In in VS with low version(such as VS2008), and following this one, an office add-in can be created, but it seems to be removed in a higher version of VS. At least, I cannot find it in VS2015. Now, what I can do is only adding an excel com reference in my project(Class Library). I don't know what to do next.

So, how could I create an Excel add-in by using COM library in VS2015? Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid VSTO? It's better than plain COM, and doesn't seem to impose any significant restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this problem through some investigation, roughly, by following the steps list here, an Excel add-in can be created through Excel COM library:

1) Create a ClassLibrary project, then add these two references to this project: Extensibility (.NET assembly) and Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library (COM Component);

2) Add a class, and implement the interface IDTExtensibility2 in Extensibility for it, we could add some code in OnConnection method;

3) Make this assembly COM-visible, in the property window of the current project, select Application tab, click the button Assembly Information, check on the corresponding item;

4) Sign the assembly, in the Signing tab, check on the “Sign the assembly”, then create a new strong name key file;

5) Add Guid and ProgId attribute for the class, the value for Guid can be found in AssemblyInfo.cs, and the ProgId is important to a COM object;

6) Build the project, and use regasm tool to make it visible to COM : regasm xxx.dll /codebase;

7) Open Registry Editor, navigate to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins, create a new subkey, the name of the new subkey need to be same with the value of ProgId, then add the following three value items:

- Description (string): `<progid value or something else>`;
- FriendlyName (string): `<progid value or a friendly name for progid>`;
- LoadBehavior (DWOWD): 3

8) Start office, the addin will be loaded automatically.